# Simple QT console TCP application. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: qt

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QTCore>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QDebug>

#define CONNECT(sndr, sig, rcvr, slt) connect(sndr, SIGNAL(sig), rcvr, SLOT(slt))

class mynet : QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    mynet()
    {}

    void start()
    {
        CONNECT(tcpServer,       newConnection(),                     this, acceptConnection());
        CONNECT(tcpClient,       connected(),                         this, startTransfer());
        CONNECT(tcpClient,       bytesWritten(qint64),                this, updateClientProgress(qint64));
        CONNECT(tcpClient,       error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError), this, displayError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError));

        // start server listening
        tcpServer->listen();
        while(!tcpServer->isListening());

        // make client connection
        tcpClient->connectToHost(QHostAddress::LocalHost, tcpServer->serverPort());
    }

public slots:
    void acceptConnection()
    {
        tcpServerConnection = tcpServer->nextPendingConnection();
        CONNECT(tcpServerConnection, readyRead(), this, updateServerProgress());
        CONNECT(tcpServerConnection, error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError), this, displayError(QAbstractSocket));
        tcpServer->close();
    }

    void startTransfer()
    {
        bytesToWrite = TotalBytes - (int)tcpClient->write(QByteArray(PayloadSize, '@'));
    }

    void updateServerProgress()
    {
        bytesReceived += (int)tcpServerConnection->bytesAvailable();
        tcpServerConnection->readAll();

        if (bytesReceived == TotalBytes)
        {
            qDebug() << "done";
            tcpServerConnection->close();
        }
    }

    void updateClientProgress(qint64 numBytes)
    {
        // callen when the TCP client has written some bytes
        bytesWritten += (int)numBytes;

        // only write more if not finished and when the Qt write buffer is below a certain size.
        if (bytesToWrite > 0 && tcpClient->bytesToWrite() <= 4*PayloadSize)
            bytesToWrite -= (int)tcpClient->write(QByteArray(qMin(bytesToWrite, PayloadSize), '@'));
    }

    void displayError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError socketError)
    {
        if (socketError == QTcpSocket::RemoteHostClosedError)
            return;

        qDebug() << tcpClient->errorString();


        tcpClient->close();
        tcpServer->close();
    }

private:
    QTcpServer* tcpServer;
    QTcpSocket* tcpClient;
    QTcpSocket* tcpServerConnection;
    int bytesToWrite;
    int bytesWritten;
    int bytesReceived;
    int TotalBytes;
    int PayloadSize;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    mynet m1;
    m1.start();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I get an

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"vtable for mynet", referenced from:
  mynet::mynet() in main.o
  mynet::~mynet()in main.o.
```

Please advise what I am doing wrong. Can I not inline the method definitions in the class for some reason in Qt?

Comment: I can't test it but this may be a problem of forgetting the `public` keyword when you inherited from `QObject`: `class mynet : public QObject` vs. `class mynet : QObject`

Comment: I will suggest you to move mynet definition to another file and separate header and implementation in .h and .cpp.

Comment: And you'll need to actually initialize all your member pointers...

Comment: @Mat I certainly would have found that I had forgot to init the pointers once this problem was fixed. But yes that was a pretty silly oversight on my part.

Comment: @Kunal I would do this in anything but prototype code.

Comment: QT       += core
QT       += network
QT       -= gui

TARGET = net
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp

Comment: Sorry I tried to format. @Julian

Comment: try adding HEADERS+=mynet.h SOURCES += mynet.cpp

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your class to the .pro file

```
HEADERS += mynet.h
SOURCES += mynet.cpp
```

so the meta-object compiler can scan them and work out they need moc'ing and generate the relevant stubs.

Comment: For this example I have the class definition and implementation in the main.cpp file. Yes not good form but this was supposed to be a trivial example from which my real program grew. There is no mynet.h or my net.cpp and MOC should be running on main.cpp.

Comment: Does QT not like definition and implementation in the same file?

Comment: Apparently not. I moved the my net class to its own .cpp/.h file and that worked fine.

Comment: moc expect to see Q_OBJECTs in a .h file that will create a .cpp file for it to include to resolve the mocced methods.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your source file is named `foo.cpp`, you have to put the following line *at the very end*:

```
#include "foo.moc"
```

This line tells qmake and the VS Qt add-in that the file should be run via moc, and that the generated moc file should be named foo.moc.

You also have problems in the `#include` lines for Qt headers. I've found that the following work:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtNetwork/QTcpServer>
#include <QtNetwork/QTcpSocket>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add network to your .pro file. This will create the correct linking to the network library functions.

```
QT       += core network
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1) You should publicly derive from QObject.

2) Are you [moc'ing](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/metaobjects.html) this file and then compiling and linking the output?  If you include the Q_OBJECT macro and don't moc, you will get an error like that.

Comment: So I set the inheritance to public for QObject. Did a clean, quake, then make. Same issue. Any advice?

Comment: Is the `moc` tool being run, and is the output of that tool being compiled and built as part of your project? (you should have a moc_xxxxxx.cpp file somewhere)

Comment: 'ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/pgsql/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/tmp/qt-stuff-85167/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.1/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/tmp/qt-stuff-85167/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.1/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "vtable for mynet", referenced from:
      mynet::mynet() in main.o
      mynet::~mynet()in main.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.'